# django model: have recursive relationship

Tags: django-models

How would I correctly model a recursive   relationship as the one illustrated below?

```
class A(models.Model):
    previous_A = models.OneToOneField(A)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With Django you can model parent-child relationships as follows:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, related_name='children')
```

Quoting the `ForeignKey` [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey):

> To create a recursive relationship – an object that has a many-to-one
>   relationship with itself – use `models.ForeignKey('self')`.

P.S. By "reflexive relationship" I assumed you are referring to a recursive association that connects a single class type (serving in one role) to itself (serving in another role); i.e. parent-child relationship.

Comment: I'm intrested in this issue too, what if you have a reflexive/recursive many-to-many relationship ?

Comment: @astrocybernaute Can you give an example of such a relationship? Never had such a requirement.

Comment: Let's say I have a recursive relationship on a "person" who can have a "manager" or several, the "manager" is also a "person" or if I take the same example below the "person" would have two "parent"

Comment: @astrocybernaute You need to create 2 `ManyToManyField` relationships. One called `manages` and the other `managed_by`. This will result in two intermediate tables to enable the relationship you describe. `manages` will link a Person to the one-to-many Persons he *manages*. `managed_by` will link a Person to the one-to-many Managers he might have managing him. Give me the link if you post this as a question, I would be able to format my answer better.

Comment: I posted a question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18442797/how-to-model-a-reflexive-many-to-many-relationship